# Python, absolute/relative import not working as expected

Tags: python, python-import

I apologize for the millionth post about this topic.
I thought I had a good grip of the whole absolute/relative import mechanism - I even replied to a couple of questions about it myself - but I'm having a problem with it and I can't figure out how to solve it.

I'm using Python 3.8.0, this is my directory structure:

```
project_folder
    scripts/
        main.py
    models/
        __init__.py
        subfolder00/
            subfolder01/
                some_script.py --> contains def for some_function
```

I need to import some_function from some_script.py when running main.py, so I tried:

**1) relative import**

```
# in main.py

from ..models.subfolder00.subfolder01.somescript import some_function
```

but when I run (from the scripts/ folder)

```
python main.py
```

this fails with error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This was expected, because I'm running main.py directly as a script, so its _*name*_ is set to _*main*_ and relative imports are bound to fail.
However, I was expecting it to work when running (always from within the scripts folder):

```
python -m main
```

but I'm getting always the same error.

**2) absolute import**

I tried changing the import in main.py to:

```
# in main.py

from models.subfolder00.subfolder01.somescript import some_function
```

and running, this time from the main project folder:

```
python scripts/main.py
```

so that - I was assuming - the starting point for the absolute import would be the project folder itself, from which it could get to models/....

But now I'm getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

Why didn't it work when using the -m option in the case of relative import, and it's not working when using absolute ones either? Which is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think quite likely you missed python's official doc ( that even come offline )
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

you'll need a dummy `__init__.py` within your module, at same level of `some_script.py`

Comment: Read that a few times :)
And, I did have __init__.py files in the package folders (I edited the question now), but still got this issue.

Comment: @Carlo you'll need that at the very deepest, same level as some_script.py, under subfolder01 , and let's say put that in each layer to play safe, and also a practical way to try little by little ( says first same level, then subfolder, then subsubfolder

Answer (score 0):

I think your "absolute" import may not have been absolute in the truest sense.

Prior to running the `python scripts/main.py` command, you would have needed to setup `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the path to `project_folder`.

Alternatively I do something like this in `main.py`:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),'..','models','subfolder00','subfolder01'))
from somescript import some_function
```

Maybe it is a little pedantic, but it makes sense to me.